# Помогите вывести первое слово до двоеточия

Tags: javascript, php, текст

У меня есть такая строка:

Александр:12:30:12345

Помогите вывести из неё первое слово

Comment: Я еще сам новичок в php но по-моему тут нужен цикл который будет перебирать знаки строки от начала и до двоеточия.

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос...как и где вы хотите это вывести...у вас метки `js`, `php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для подобных задач существует [strstr()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strstr.php), регулярки тут избыточны.

```
$str = 'Александр:12:30:12345';

echo strstr($str, ':', true);
```

---

[**Демо**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/79d51874473d6526bceeb4d9561a50a1cfbb8479)

Answer (score 1):

javascript:

```js
let stringPart = "Александр:12:30:12345".split(":")[0];

console.log(stringPart);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'Александр:12:30:12345'.match(/[^:]+/)[0] - работает и на js, и на php :)
```

Comment: Поделитесь,пожалуйста, ссылками на данные методы, не получается найти.

Comment: Загуглите "регулярные выражения". Информации немало)

Comment: Да мне бы ссылку на php функцию `match` только надо.

Comment: А, вы об этом :) Этот код выполнен на js, не факт, что match есть в php. Когда я говорил что работает и там, и там - я имел ввиду регулярные выражения в общем :))

Comment: Так вы уточняйте ) что регулярка подходит для обоих языков. А то я подумал, что-то новое в PHP появилось. На PHP то лучше [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php) использовать или [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php).