# Помогите вывести первое слово до двоеточий php

Tags: javascript, php, html, текст

Мне нужно вывести слово Андрей из этой строки:
Андрей::12::1ea8

Comment: Дубль [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995216/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f)... Флешмоб - задай вопрос со ста акков своих??

Comment: Вы Андрей, Артём или Александр?

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'USER@EXAMPLE.com';
stristr($email, 'e', true); // Начиная с PHP 5.3.0, выводит US
```

Документация: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stristr.php